# Error with class in C#

Tags: c#

Hi I have a problem with class.

I created Function.cs class where I have all my function:

```
 public class Function
{
    public void Plus(Form1 form)
    {
        decimal multiple = 0.3m;
        decimal digit = Convert.ToDecimal(form.TextBox1Text);
        form.TextBox2Text = String.Format("{0:f}", (digit * multiple) + digit);
    }
```

On Form1.cs I called this class

```
else if (textbox.Text != string.Empty && textbox2.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                Function.Plus(); //error
            }
```

And I have an error on Function.Plus().

Comment: `Plus` is an instance method so you'll need to create an instance of type `Function` or make `Plus` static. Also note that you'll need to pass an object of type `Form` to the argument of `Plus`

Comment: You defined your method `Plus` with a parameter, but then you do not pass that parameter when you call it. That would certainly result in an error. Also, have you instantiated `Function`? Otherwise that gives you another error. Maybe you could tell us what error you are getting, so we do not have to guess?

Comment: I dont think its a good idea to access controls of `Form` directly in a  separate class. e.g. `Plus` function accesses 'form.TextBox1Text' directly. Better to pass the text from `TextBox1'.

Comment: @oerkelens error message:
"There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'form' of 'Function.Plus(Form1)'

Comment: You have to pass your form there. Why do you need your Form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate your Function class or make the Plus method static

**Instantiation:**

*Function.cs*

```
public class Function
{
    public void Plus(Form1 form)
    {
        decimal multiple = 0.3m;
        decimal digit = Convert.ToDecimal(form.TextBox1Text);
        form.TextBox2Text = String.Format("{0:f}", (digit * multiple) + digit);
    }
}
```

*Main.cs*

```
else if (textbox.Text != string.Empty && textbox2.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                var function = new Function();
                function.Plus(); //error
            }
```

**Making the used method static**

Or else you can just make the Plus method static :

*Function.cs*

```
public class Function
{
    public static void Plus(Form1 form)
    {
        decimal multiple = 0.3m;
        decimal digit = Convert.ToDecimal(form.TextBox1Text);
        form.TextBox2Text = String.Format("{0:f}", (digit * multiple) + digit);
    }
}
```

*Main.cs*

```
else if (textbox.Text != string.Empty && textbox2.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                Function.Plus(); //error
            }
```

Moreover, if you make the method static you will **need** to pass an argument of type Form1 to your function, and can no longer use a field of the Function class if there was one used.

Comment: your code doesn't compile. A static class must not have instance methods. Also, OP might only want this particular method to be static rather than the whole class, therefore, you should just declare `Plus` as static.

Comment: @Aominè : Right, I just edited my answer to take your remarks into account.

Comment: To complete your answer, you should notify OP that _you'll need to pass a reference of type Form to the Plus method_.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a new object of your class. And then call your Plus function.

```
Function obj = new Function();
obj .Plus(//here you have to pass your argument of Form type)
```